# Make nginx configurable with kubernetes secret?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, openresty

I have a working openresty with lua-resty-openidc as ingress controller.
Now, the nginx.conf is hardcoded in my image, with something like this :

```
    server {
        server_name  _;
        listen       80;

        location /OAuth2Client {
            access_by_lua_block {
                local opts = {
                    discovery = "/.well-known/openid-configuration",
                    redirect_uri = "/authorization-code/callback",
                    client_id = "clientID",
                    client_secret = "clientSecret",
                    scope = "openid profile somethingElse",
                }
    ...
            }
            proxy_pass http://clusterIp/OAuth2Client;
        }
    }
```

As Nginx doesn't accept environment variables, is there a simple way to make my nginx.conf configurable, for ex

```
    server {
        server_name  ${myServerName};
        listen       ${myServerPort};

        location /${specificProjectRoot} {
            access_by_lua_block {
                local opts = {
                    discovery = "${oidc-provider-dev-url}/.well-known/openid-configuration",
                    redirect_uri = "${specificProjectRoot}/authorization-code/callback",
                    client_id = "${myClientId}",
                    client_secret = "${myClientSecret}",
                    scope = "${myScopes}",
                }
    ...
            }
            proxy_pass http://${myClusterIP}/${specificProjectRoot};
        }
    }
```

so that whatever team in whatever namespace could reuse my image and just provide a kubernetes secret containing their specific config for their project ?

Comment: What if you create a "start_script.sh" to run whenever your nginx is started? In the script you can use the environment variables and using `sed` you can replace the values in your nginx.conf. something like that: `sed -i -e "s,\${myServerName},$SERVER_NAME," /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to render the `nginx.conf` from a templated version at runtime (as Juliano's comment mentions). To do this, your `Dockerfile` could look something like this:

```
FROM nginx
COPY nginx.conf.template /etc/nginx/
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "envsubst < /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.template > /etc/nginx/nginx.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
```

Notice that it copies `nginx.conf.template` into your image, this would be your templated config with variables in the form `${MY_SERVER_NAME}` where `MY_SERVER_NAME` is [injected into your pod as an environment variable](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables) via your Kubernetes manifest, from your configmap or secret or however you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

While `envsubst` is a good workaround to connect Kubernetes objects with container files, Kubernetes native `ConfigMap`s are designed precisely for this purpose: passing non-sensitive key-value data to the container, including entire files like your `nginx.conf`.

Here's a working example (in the question AND answer) of a `ConfigMap` and `Deployment` pair specifically for NGINX:

- [Custom nginx.conf from ConfigMap in Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64178370/custom-nginx-conf-from-configmap-in-kubernetes)