# Minikube only allow curl to service with port 80?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, qemu

I create Deployment and expose Service with the manifest file below. When I use port 80 I can curl http://$(minikube ip):32000, and minikube ssh I also curl . However, when I changed the port to difference 80, it couldn't connect. Does it mean do run minikube service only on port 80?

environment:

- macos
- minikube v1.32.0
- qemu2 driver based
- Kubernetes v1.28.3 on Docker 24.0.7

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: nginx-deployment
  name: nginx-deployment
  namespace: isocias-dev
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-deployment
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: nginx-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx-deployment
        resources: {}
status: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: nginx-deployment
  name: nginx-deployment
  namespace: isocias-dev
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8099
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8099
    nodePort: 32000
  selector:
    app: nginx-deployment
  type: NodePort
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: Did you configure nginx to also listen on port 8099?

Comment: @VasiliiAngapov: in the manifest file, I defined the container nginx port as 8099. However, my problem is not by the Nginx port, it is the port of service because when I change ```targetPort: 80``` it runs correctly

Comment: Your problem is that Nginx listens on 80. If you want it to listen on 8099 you have to adjust its config.

Comment: Could you give me a suggestion about keywords to search it? I searched but it showed results about changing container Pod ports in Kubernetes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64178370/custom-nginx-conf-from-configmap-in-kubernetes

Comment: You can also try adding environment variable NGINX_PORT=8099

Comment: i add into spec.template.spec.containers:  env: - name: NGINX_PORT value: "8099".
then run ```kubectl -n isocias-dev exec -it nginx-deployment-66c6d45d4f-65rqr -- printenv``` 
it print result ```PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin NGINX_PORT=8099 ..... ``` 
it still dont' access with port 8099

Comment: Have you checked if there are any network policies that might restrict communication on the port?